# Creating Sencha touch 2 app dashboard

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am developing a sencha touch 2 app. My app should authenticate a user and load a dynamic dashboard according to user authorization (could be different menu icons for different users).

My question: which sencha touch 2 component is more suitable for dynamic dashboard (menu) creation? I guess my dashboard look like as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Using an Ext.DataView with a little CSS magic making the items 25% large should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very much like thumbnail gallery/list shown in [Touch Style example](http://www.shopstyleapp.com/app/) bundled with Sencha touch library in examples folder. As @TDeBailleul said this can be done with DataView but if you feel that is little tricky or touch you can use template approach easily.